# No correct association of name and percentage to create a pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart, percentage

I want to create a simple pie chart, with data from one column. The variations there are name_yes, name_no, what the pie chart should show with name and percentage at the end.

So this is the code I hava, running fine, with export but the labeling is wrong and shows 2x name_yes.
Maybe there is the problem, for the wrong output of the pie chart.

[The pie chart displays the correct percentage but the wrong label with 2x yes, and not like it should 1x no and 1x yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t4qL.png)
Here ist the pie chart:

```
png(file="hydrologicalp.png", width=600, height=400)
hydrological <- xname$hydrological
hydrologicalp <- paste(hydrological, round((table(hydrological)/sum(table(hydrological)))*100), "%", sep = " ")
pie(table(hydrological), label = hydrologicalp, main = "hydrological")
dev.off()
```

Having a look at the created "hydrologicalp" table shows, that the percentage values arte just given alternately, without correct association to the name_yes ore name_no.
The hydrologicalp Table:

```
hydrologicalp
  [1] "hydrological_yes 28 %" "hydrological_yes 72 %"
  [3] "hydrological_yes 28 %" "hydrological_yes 72 %"
  [5] "hydrological_yes 28 %" "hydrological_yes 72 %"
  [7] "hydrological_no 28 %"  "hydrological_yes 72 %"
  [9] "hydrological_yes 28 %" "hydrological_yes 72 %"
....... and so on
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needed to have made hydrological unique before you paste it together with the results of tabling it.
p.s. I was a bit annoyed about having to make representative data to get this up and running; in the future when seeking assistance please take steps towards this critical element.

```
hydrological <- c("a","a","b")
(hydrologicalp <- paste(unique(hydrological), round((table(hydrological)/sum(table(hydrological)))*100), "%", sep = " "))
pie(table(hydrological), label = hydrologicalp, main = "hydrological")
```